# React.js starting on development server or creating production build requires to wait long time?

Tags: reactjs, build, development-environment, production

When starting react.js in development it needs like 3 or 5 minutes to load. The time varies, after it's started it refreshes fast enough on changes...

Also when doing production build it takes a lot of time.

What could cause this?
There are some huge components some are like 500~ lines there are some of components that has ~2k lines.
Could huge components cause this?

---

First update - tried to start react app in development 4 times today.

1. First start in development took 4 mins 10 sec.
2. Second start in development took 3 mins 12 sec.
3. Third start in development took 2 mins 30 sec.
4. Fourth start in development took 2 mins 35 sec.

Also tried to build production build and look how long it exactly takes.

1. First production build - 7mins 27seconds.
2. Second production build - 3mins 41 seconds.
3. Third production build(removed all build files) - 3mins 34 seconds.

Also those big components who has from 500 to 2k lines of code are not my design choice. When I joined project I just found it like that. Now I am just figuring out is it okay that it takes such period of time to start development server for react.

Output message when build finished:

```
File sizes after gzip:

  2.37 MB   build/static/js/2.6d79667f.chunk.js
  72.79 KB  build/static/css/2.37cd983e.chunk.css
  52.85 KB  build/static/js/main.375a34e0.chunk.js
  2.17 KB   build/static/css/main.5827d774.chunk.css
  796 B     build/static/js/runtime-main.a4023761.js

The bundle size is significantly larger than recommended.
Consider reducing it with code splitting: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#code-splitting
You can also analyze the project dependencies: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#analyzing-the-bundle-size

The project was built assuming it is hosted at http://localhost:5050/.
You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.

The build folder is ready to be deployed.

Find out more about deployment here:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template/template/README.md
```

---

Comment: with it been a development build looking at the output provided those chunk sizes are to be expected. If you ran a production build you would see the top chunk at 2.37MB come down to only KB's..  the reason production builds take longer than development is because production has to build everything, development will use whats there as normally you have all your node packages built and ready. I would look at the number of node packages you are using, are they up to date? are there any redundant ones?

Comment: Am I doing something wrong? For example the output shown is production build's output. And after all processing the biggest chunk takes 2.37MB up in memory? It is like final size for that chunk which will be served to the user?

Comment: something is wrong as you shouldn't have a JS of that size been served on a production build. i wouldn't be happy about using your app and having to download a single JS file that is 2.37MB. i would start doing a code review to understand what is going into that chunk and also what you can do to improve the size.

Comment: install source-map-explorer https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer and you should be able to identify what is included and what is causing the size issue.

Comment: Wow @Richard I want to really thank you. This tool made it all clear why that chunk is so huge! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

This happens when your app has more components along with static contents. When you also build react js production it does take time to build an optimized build. You can follow below link for optimization:
https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/optimizing-loading-time-for-big-react-apps-cf13bbf63c57

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, I think the server is fast but if you are doing the production build it will take some minutes, depends on how much code you have, if it's your hello world and it doesn't charge I think something is bad

Comment: There needs to be more information provided in your answer as it doesn't help towards answering the question. I would ask why do some components have 2k lines of code? is there a better way of splitting out the components and functions to be reusable? could the OP provide some code samples to review. The Question itself is too broad also. I think depending on the build anything within a few minutes is acceptable I would ask for a build log from the OP and we can go from there to help them identify the issues.